# Pyspark: help filtering out any rows which have unwanted characters

Tags: python, pyspark

Writing to a parquet file gives me an error that states that `" ,;{}()\n\t="` characters are not allowed.

I'd like to eliminate rows that have any of these characters anywhere.

Would I use "like", "rlike" or something else?

I have tried this:

```
df = df.filter(df.account_number.rlike('*\n*', '*\ *','*,*','*;*','*{*','*}*','*)*','*(*','*\t*') == False)
```

Obviously this does not work.  I'm unsure what the right regex syntax is, or if I even need a regex in this particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `rlike` since it's for regular expressions:

```
df.filter(~df.account_number.rlike("[ ,;{}()\n\t=]"))
```

When you put characters between `[]` it means any of the following characters.

I don't see why these characters wouldn't be allowed in the dataframe rows, there might be an invalid character in the column names instead. You can use `.withColumnRenamed()` to rename it.